# listing existing images in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a strange issue with CKeditor. 
If I upload the images through the inbuild uploader function, the thumbnails are created and everything is working as intended.

However, If i use an existing image directory, CKeditor is not loading those images.. or if I upload manually through FTP, the images are not showing in CKeditor.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I have tried to google various solutions but currently I am unsure what I should search for.
will remote image location solve the issue or should I do any other configurations

Answer (score 0):

By using a remote file location, u can map the shared files with remote location and it will solve the issue